# How to get file name when click the relation file in mfc code?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2008, mfc

How to get file name when click the relation file in mfc code?

For Now, I create file relation to file and executing application,

when I click the relation file will open the application, but I can't get file name.

what method could I get the file name, which function which variable to get file name

For another example, using OndropFile, DragQueryFile will get the
file name save in strFilePath variable, as follow code；

But I need click file method, not dropfile.

My application is MDI.

```
void CTerchy_CurveViewView::OnDropFiles(HDROP hDropInfo)
{
CString strPath;
WCHAR strFilePath[MAX_PATH];
::DragQueryFile(hDropInfo, 0, strFilePath, sizeof(strFilePath));

strPath = strFilePath;
if(strPath.Right(4) == _T(".GRP") || strPath.Right(4) == _T(".grp") ||
    strPath.Right(5) == _T(".7215") || strPath.Right(5) == _T(".8103"))
{
```

File relation setting：

```
Command: Executing application
Description: None
Extensions：GRP
MIME："%1"
```

I find a web site which talks about File relation: [File Associations In Visual Studio](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/58005-file-associations-in-visual-studio/)

> The default for"Arguments" is "%1",Which means to pass the full path
>   and filename to your application.

how do I Get the file name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, Thanks everybody, the method of get file name, the application already impletement,
Open MyAppView.cpp

```
// 剖析標準 Shell 命令、DDE、檔案開啟舊檔的命令列
CCommandLineInfo cmdInfo;
ParseCommandLine(cmdInfo);

/* 檔案關聯開啟的檔名 */
strRelationFile = cmdInfo.m_strFileName;
```

I got it.

Answer (score 0):

For SDI you get the filename on the command line. In a standard application you can use CCommandLine. The filename is stored there.

For MDI application the DDE Interface is used and the internal frame work opens the file via DDE. OpenDocument

Answer (score 0):

The file name associated with a MFC `CDocument` object is available via [CDocument::GetPathName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/fzw1zy9s%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)